# How to add div to an existing table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `table` and a `div`, the `div`'s CSS property is set to `display: none` (unvisible), I need to add my `div` to each `td` in my table dynamically. I thought about getting my `div` using jQuery and add it to my table's `td`s and change the CSS property to  `display: block` (visible). Is it possible ?

My code :

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <div style="display:none">
   <label id="addVideo" for="uploadFileVideo">Add Video</label>
   <input id="uploadFileVideo" type='file'style="width:300px;visibility:hidden"/>                                                                                      
 </div>
```

Comment: yes, the same div to each td.

Comment: `$('table td').html($('#divId').html())` this would do.

Comment: Check this fiddle, You just need to add an Id to the table and a class name to the div

http://jsfiddle.net/shamanth7077/cyuyc0rk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the classes `.my-table` and `.my-div` to your `table` and `div` and then using jQuery:

```
$('.my-table td').each(function () {
    $('.my-div')
        .clone()    
        .appendTo(this)
        .show();
});
```

What it does:

- `$('.my-table td').each(f)`: searches for all `td`s and executes the specified `function` for each of them
- `.clone()`: clones the invisible div (that is to be added to multiple locations)
- `.appendTo(this)`: appends to matched `td` (`this` refers to the matched `DOM` Element `td`)
- `.show()`: removes display: none

#### [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yyfcdp8a/)

**Note:** Although this will do what you asked for it to do, the html will be invalid since you will produce **multiple elements with the same id**, which is illegal. Therefore either

- Switch to using classes
  or
- Manipulate the ids, and make sure they are unique

Answer (score 1):

Use `cloneNode`. And loop your td's with `appendChild`:

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
tds.forEach(function(td) {
    var newDiv = div.cloneNode();
    newDiv.style.display = 'block';
    td.appendChild(newDiv);
});
```

No jQuery needed! ;)

Comment: thank you,I need to select the specific table (can't select all tds..)

Comment: call `specificTable.querySelectorAll('td');` then

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

Something like this!

Css

```
<style type="text/css">
    td { border: 1px solid black; }

</style>
```

Script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function tryIt(){
        $("td").each(function(){
            $(this).html($('.testDiv').html());
        });
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick="tryIt()">Try It</button>
    <div class="testDiv" style="display:none">
        <label id="addVideo" for="uploadFileVideo">Add Video</label>
        <input id="uploadFileVideo" type='file'style="width:300px;"/>    
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will help you

HTML

```
<body>
 <table class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td> 
    </tr>
 </table>

 <div class="testDiv" style="display:none">
     <label id="addVideo" for="uploadFileVideo">Add Video</label>
     <input id="uploadFileVideo" type='file'style="width:300px;"/>    
 </div>
```

Script:

```
var $table = $('.myTable');
$($table).find('td').append($('.testDiv').show());
```

Demo:

**[Running Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yyfcdp8a/7/)**

Comment: It is good, but it only add my div to 1 td and I need my div in each td.

Comment: Just check the running demo it will add div to each td

Comment: I recheck it and the problem is that the div become visible but is not a node under td.. thats why I got only one div and not two.. cant use your code unfortunately..

Comment: Hey Damkulul .. In running demo, you can see in generated source that  div is generated under each td , if you do not need this then provide the complete static code which you want to generate.